# rails: how to build a batch of objects in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am facing a tricky challenge (as a rails beginnner) and I did not find so far any solution that responds to my needs.

I have a `User` model who `has_many :events`.

Here is my current form for creating an event :

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :starts_at %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :starts_at %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In order to display an user-friendly form, I would like to POST not only an event at a time but many that shares a same value. Eg:

The user selects one value for `starts_at` attribute and then can choose multiple values for `title` using checkboxes. This should create then as many events as checked checkboxes and with the same `starts_at` value.

I am thinking about sending a params hash `params[:events]` that contains an array of events, and then do smg like `@event = current_user.events.create(params[:events])` but I do not know how to write it in my view and my controller.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Accepts nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) will help you, works really well with [Ryan Bs nested form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)